# OmniFaces inputFile case insensitive media type filtering

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I'm using [OmniFaces's 2.6.1 inputFile](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/inputFile) to upload files and want to apply media type filtering through the use of the accept attribute, for example `accept="image/png"`. This works fine for file names having a `.png` extension, but is apparently case sensitive. When uploading a file with a `.PNG` extension, the validation fails. I tried specifying `accept="image/PNG"` and `accept="image/*"`, but to no avail.

Is there an easy way to filter on media types in a case insensitive way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the covers, the `<o:inputFile>` derives the mime type from the server's mime mapping, which you can control via `<mime-mapping>` entries in `web.xml`.

I can't reproduce your problem on WildFly 12. Apparently you're using a server which doesn't perform case insensitive matching on the file extension.

As per [issue 447](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/447) I've fixed it for 2.6.9 by explicitly lowercasing the filename before consulting the server-managed mime mapping. For now, a work around is to explicitly add a mime mapping for `PNG` extension to your webapp's `web.xml`.

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>PNG</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Note that this still won't match `Png`, `pNG`, `pNg`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer BalusC. I'm using Websphere Liberty Profile 16.0.0.4 and explicitly adding the mime mapping works fine. Thank you for the OmniFaces's fix as well!